# how do you check to see if your cinnamon desktop is running with 3D acceleration (i.e. not "software rendering")?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cinnamon, desktop, productivity

I have a VM that is sluggish and I think I fixed the issue but I want to make sure the cinnamon desktop is running with 3D acceleration (i.e. not "software rendering").

How do you check to see if your cinnamon desktop is running with 3D acceleration (i.e. not "software rendering")?

Answer (score 3):

#### pre-req:

- [if you are using a VM] in virtualbox for your VM make sure you have 3d-acceleration marked as enabled (check box is checked)
- [if you are using a VM] in virtualbox make sure you have >= 12-16MB video memory

#### method 1:

- at the GUI login make sure to click the cog before entering your password and hitting the keyboard enter key --> select cinnamon (not the one that says "software rendering")
- when your screen displays the desktop make sure there isn't any dialog that says something about "runnging software rendering"

#### method 2:

on the command line run `glxinfo|grep Accel` and it should say yes

#### method 3:

- on the command line run `glxinfo|grep render` and look for "OpenGL renderer"

#### final check:

- run `glxgears` and make sure it reports >50 frames per second

#### disclaimer

i'm no expert on this but i wanted to share to help everyone out. i got this info mostly from: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1077320-start-0.html

#### if you are running a `vncserver` i don't think vnc can do 3D acceleration

- like the section says: if you are running a `vncserver` i don't think vnc can do 3D acceleration
- the third-party sources I read seem to indicate that VNC can't do 3D acceleration: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174563 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048527
- if you are running a `virtualbox` VM you can double click the VM to open the VM through the GUI and get 3D acceleration (or if you have a license for the non-free extension pack you can run a remote-desktop instead of a `vncserver` and get better performance but make sure you have a purchased license for the extension pack. lastly there is probably a way to run your own remote-desktop server like vncserver but i don't know how to do that.)